# how to loop to expect a list of item in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ts-jest

I have added the below jest unit test to render a component and I am expecting some of its elements using "getAllByText" as there are multiple similar elements. I got a review comment to loop over the list of element if there are more than 1 and expect each of them to be visible. Can someone please help me in modifying the test to loop over all the elements.

```
it('should render seat total wrapper on small breakpoint', () => {
    render(
      <MockViewportProvider viewSize={ViewSizes.SMALL}>
        <SeatMapContext.Provider value={{ state: contextObj, dispatch: noop }}>
          <SeatMapCabinAndSeatWrapper
            flightSeatMapPlaneData={seatMapPlanesData}
            flightLegsDetails={FlightLegsDetails}
            onChangeLegIndex={jest.fn}
            selectedLegIndex={0}
            handleLegendButtonClick={jest.fn()}
            handleApplySeatSelection={handleApplySeatSelection}
          />
        </SeatMapContext.Provider>
      </MockViewportProvider>
    );
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next Flight' })).toBeVisible();
    expect(screen.getAllByText('$276.24')[0]).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Review comments -> "if there are expected to be more than 1 item then please loop over the list and expect each element to be visible
if there should only be 1 item then please determine how to use getByText".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a for loop.

```
for (const element of screen.getAllByText('$276.24')) {
    expect(element).toBeVisible();
}
```

For an implementation with no `for..of` loop:

```
const list = screen.getAllByText('$276.24');
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    expect(list[i]).toBeVisible();
}
```

Or:

```
screen.getAllByText('$276.24').forEach((element) => {
    expect(element).toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: Though this approach worked but somehow I am getting this lint error - "  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations " . Is there a way we can loop without using for.

Comment: This is due to the `for..of` loop, it is "relatively" new syntax. You can use a normal `for (var i;...)` loop, or I believe also `arr.forEach`. I have added examples in the answer